# Get every month of the current year in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using the following code to get the date of every day in the current week, in SQL Server:

```
SELECT 
    DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, GETDATE()), 0) Monday,
    DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, GETDATE()), 0) + 1 Tuesday,
    DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, GETDATE()), 0) + 2 Wednsday,
    DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, GETDATE()), 0) + 3 Thursday,
    DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, GETDATE()), 0) + 4 Friday,
    DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, GETDATE()), 0) + 5 Saturday,
    DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, GETDATE()), 0) + 6 Sunday;
```

I'm using this query to fill a bar chart in a asp.net application.

I need the same thing but with the months of the current year.

Can you help me with this, please?

Edit: More like a query to retrieve data from every month of this year.

Comment: Do you want to list the months of the year? or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes. Maybe is a query to retrieve data from every month of this year.

Comment: `SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), 1, 1) AS January, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), 2, 1) AS February, ...`

Comment: What are you expecting as output? The first date of every month for the current year?

Comment: The first and the last day of January, of THIS year. And Feb, March, etc. Is there a code to perform this??

Comment: @Joroen "DATEFROMPARTS"  is not a recognized built-in function name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return the first and last day of every month for the current year.

```
select FirstDay = dateadd(month, thisMonth - 1, dateadd(year, datediff(year, 0, getdate()), 0))
    , LastDay = dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(month, thisMonth, dateadd(year, datediff(year, 0, getdate()), 0)))
from
(
    values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)
) x(thisMonth)
```

Comment: This. I think I can work with this. Thank you so much.

Comment: Why not just use `EOMonth()`?

Comment: @Brian sure that works too. However that isn't available until 2012 and the OP stated that DATEFROMPARTS was an invalid function so I assume they are on 2008 or earlier.

Comment: That, sir, is a valid reason not to use `EOMonth()`  :)